# do browsers remove # in URL automatically?

Tags: url, hash

our front end guy needs to form a url containing the hash, (i.e, http://blah/#some-link.) when we hit this on the browser and inspect the http traffic using fiddler, we saw that everything after blah/ gets removed, so the request is really just http://blah/.  we also confirmed this on our server eclipse debug log.

the request gets redirected to the correct login page by Spring security(because user hasn't logged in), but the url on the browser now shows:
http://blah/some-link  (the hash got removed) but the url on the browser should really be http://blah/log-in.

any idea why this is?  any fix or workaround?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URI part after `#` is called a `fragment`:

`URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`

Scheme and hier-part identify the location of a document, and fragment helps the browser to identify a location inside this document.

Fragment is stripped from URI by client software before it is sent as a part of request.

From [RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
>   processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
>   from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
>   identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
>   solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.  Although
>   this separate handling is often perceived to be a loss of
>   information, particularly for accurate redirection of references as
>   resources move over time, it also serves to prevent information
>   providers from denying reference authors the right to refer to
>   information within a resource selectively.

Comment: That alone doesn't explain why the server isn't seeing it.  After all, the query string (after "?") is visible to the server.

Answer (score 5):

Content after the `#` is only used on the client side, per HTTP specification.  If you require that information on the server, you can either use a different separator, or you can submit it via ajax after the page has loaded by reading it on the client with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the URI including and after the hash (#) is never sent to the server as part of the HTTP request.

The reason is that the hash identifier was originally designed to point at references within the given web page and not to new resources on the server.

If you want to get the hash identifier, you'll have to use some client-side JavaScript to grab the value and submit it with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmark is removed from URL when the back button is clicked in IE9, IE10 or IE11

In IE10 , first time on clicking the HREF link leads to the correct below url:
http://www.example.com/yy/zz/ff/paul.html#20007_14

If back button is clicked again the, then it comes to the below url:
http://www.example.com/yy/zz/ff/paul.html

Solution :

Please change the url with https

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with javascript

```
 <script>
 if(window.location.hash) {
    console.log(window.location.hash); 
    window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
 } 
</script>
```