# UBER API - Access Code Format

Tags: php, uber-api

I am using a PHP integration with UBER API. I am having trouble with the OAuth flow. I get `{"error": "invalid_grant"}` after trying to exchange an access code for an access token.

It was working well, but today it just stopped working. Debugging it, I see that Uber is providing access code in this format:  `IPjvWABDxk00000BxQQwJksP2I50qD#_`  and I believe that the "`#_`" at the end is causing me problems, as php `$_GET` won't be able to read the full string (from `IP`.. to ...`#_`).
My code:

```
$uber_access_code = $_GET["code"]; 

        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
        'client_secret' => $uber_client_secret,
        'client_id' => $uber_client_id,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $uber_access_code,
        'redirect_uri' =>  $uber_redirect_uri,

        );

        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();   
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
```

Question: How can I read the full string parameter from PHP? $_GET trims "`#_`" on my end, but I need the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested it on my local machine I can replicate your problem, but I don't think it is a php problem. It looks like it is a browser issue. Since when I checked the apache access logs I can see it is sending request like.

```
"GET /result.php?code=IPjvWABDxk00000BxQQwJksP2I50qD HTTP/1.1" 200 148
```

If you are the one who is creating this GET request URL you can do the following.

For e.g.
form.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $link = base64_encode('IPjvWABDxk00000BxQQwJksP2I50qD#_');
        ?>
        <a href="result.php?code=<?php echo $link;?>">link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result.php

```
<?php
var_dump(base64_decode($_GET['code']));
?>
```

and you get valid result like

```
string 'IPjvWABDxk00000BxQQwJksP2I50qD#_' (length=32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @ksoni. However, the code is generated by UBER. They just do a 302 redirect with a "?code=" parameter on the URI. So, I can't control how they format it and need to read exacly how they send it (that's the issue).

Comment: @Olecramoak It might not be obvious but # is used as anchor which is mostly for only for browser to be understood. So as long as you have that in your URL it will not work as expected. I believe it is just matter of asking them to change the code for you. Sorry I can't see any other work around for it.

Comment: You can ask them to base64 encode. As I said the access log shows it not received by php so you cannot fix at php end, unless you change the url through whatever mechanism available to you

Comment: @Olecramoak Please refer to this answer to get more understanding how fragments are removed by the useragent https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384464/3966730